# Form not Submitting value when clicking submit button

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, forms, django-forms

I am using django forms to submit a report. But after clicking on submit button it sends POST request but no data is added in POST request.

this is my forms.py

```
class WeeklyForm(forms.Form): 

    tname = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=CustomTeacher.objects.values_list('tname', flat = True), widget =forms.Select( attrs ={'class': 'form-control' , 'placeholder' : ' Teachers Name '}))

    sname = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=CustomStudent.objects.values_list('sname', flat = True), widget =forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple( attrs ={'class': 'form-control' 'form-check-input' 'form-check-inline', 'placeholder' : ' Students Name '}))

    class_name = forms.CharField(widget= forms.Select(choices= [('1', 'UKG'), ('2', 'Class 1'), ('3', 'LKG'), ('4', 'Montessori') ] ,attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Select Class'}))

    date =  forms.DateField(initial = datetime.date.today() , required=False, widget =forms.DateInput( attrs ={'class': 'form-control' , 'placeholder' : ' Date ', 'name' : 'date'}))

    objective = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'objective'}))
 
    target = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'target'}))
    
    how = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'how?'}))
    
    material = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'material required'}))

    support = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Any Support Required?'}))
```

This is function from views.py which I am using to get data and insert into database

view.py

```
def weekly(request):
    
    context = ''
    form = WeeklyForm()
    context = {'form': form} 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WeeklyForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            tname1 = form.cleaned_data['teachers']
            sname1 = form.cleaned_data['students']
            date1 = form.cleaned_data['date']
            objective1 = form.cleaned_data['objective']
            tplan1 = form.cleaned_data['target']
            how1 = form.cleaned_data['how']
            material1 = form.cleaned_data['material']
            extra1 = form.cleaned_data['support']

            print (tname1)
            report = wreport(tname = tname1, sname = sname1, fdate = date1, objective = objective1, tplan = tplan1, how = how1, material = material1, extra = extra1)
            report.save()

            messages.success(request, "Your report was submitted Successfully.")
    else:
            form = WeeklyForm()
            context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'teacher/weekly.html', context)
```

I am showing only an example of template as there are many lines of codes.
weekly.html

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- Teacher section  -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 mb-2">
            <div><strong>Teacher's Name:</strong></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            {{ form.teachers }}
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Student section -->
    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <!-- name="sname" id="sname" -->
            <div><strong>Student's Name:</strong></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">

            <div class="form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <!-- {% for student in students %}
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="">
                        {{student.sname}}
                    {% endfor %} -->
                </label>
            </div>
            {{ form.sname }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- submit button  -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="mx-auto">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4 shadow" style="border-radius:25px;">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have tried debugging and printing values I am receiving from form but nothing gets printed.

Edit: After further debugging I found out that my form is not validating this are errors I caught with `form.errors` function

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>tname<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a list of values.</li></ul></li><li>sname<ul class="errorlist"><li>“Test Student” is not a valid value.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Comment: can you just put you HTML because I think you did not use ```{{ form }}``` tag in your HTML

Comment: @l.b.vasoya I am not call `{{ form }}` in html instead I am calling it as `{{ form.teacher }}` as you can see in code because I want to get fields in their proper section as I am using custom html styling and bootstrap with form. So I am only calling a field from form in respective div in html.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** When you used queryset attribute you need to assign queryset and whenever used choices attribute you need to assign list or dict

**Second:** while You trying to do request same URL. You have to remove **action** in your form

and while you want to do a request on another URL. you have to add action url of the view which is calling

Here form.py

```
class WeeklyForm(forms.Form): 

    tname = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=CustomTeacher.objects.all(), widget =forms.Select( attrs ={'class': 'form-control' , 'placeholder' : ' Teachers Name '}))

    sname = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=CustomStudent.objects.all(), widget =forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple( attrs ={'class': 'form-control' 'form-check-input' 'form-check-inline', 'placeholder' : ' Students Name '}))

    class_name = forms.CharField(widget= forms.Select(choices= [('1', 'UKG'), ('2', 'Class 1'), ('3', 'LKG'), ('4', 'Montessori') ] ,attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Select Class'}))

    date =  forms.DateField(initial = datetime.date.today() , required=False, widget =forms.DateInput( attrs ={'class': 'form-control' , 'placeholder' : ' Date ', 'name' : 'date'}))

    objective = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'objective'}))
 
    target = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'target'}))
    
    how = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'how?'}))
    
    material = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'material required'}))

    support = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Any Support Required?'}))
```

Here I consider as requested on the same URL

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- Teacher section  -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 mb-2">
            <div><strong>Teachers Name:</strong></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            {{ form.teachers }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- submit button  -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="mx-auto">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4 shadow" style="border-radius:25px;">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is view

```
def weekly(request):
    
    context = ''
    form = WeeklyForm()
    context = {'form': form} 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WeeklyForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            print (data)

            report = wreport(tname = data['teachers'], sname = data['students'], fdate = data['date'], objective = data['objective'], tplan = data['target'], how = data['how'], material = data['material'], extra = data['support'])
            report.save()

            messages.success(request, "Your report was submitted Successfully.")
    else:
            form = WeeklyForm()
            context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'teacher/weekly.html', context)
```

Hope you understand what I trying to say let me know any query concern

Comment: Thanks for Answer. After debugging my question i found out that form is not validating for `sname` I will update html for that section and `form.errors`.

Comment: so I think you have to answer on your question and accept that as of right in future community people could see and get the problem and it answer i would be great for all off us

Comment: Unfortunately, That is not an answer. I am unable to understand why is form not validating for checkbox.  with `CheckboxSelectMultiple` field in form.

Comment: You have to pass ```sname = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=CustomStudent.objects.all(), widget =forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple( attrs ={'class': 'form-control' 'form-check-input' 'form-check-inline', 'placeholder' : ' Students Name '})
```
You need to  pass queryset on queryset attribute if you use choices then you have to modify and assign list or dict of choice let me know it work

Comment: After clearing error for sname now it apprears for tname which is a dropdown field So i used `forms.select` As you can see for the queryset I have updated queryset for tname field as well. this is new error `<ul class="errorlist"><li>tname<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a list of values.</li></ul></li></ul>`

Comment: i am updating my answer check it then tell me

Comment: I followed what you said regarding query. but problem is still the same.. One i mentioned in my above comment. It didn't get fixed.

Comment: check more than two-element on those multiple selections then update required false it will work?

Comment: No, Selecting multiple for checkbox field doesn't help. The error as you can see in above comment appears to be from tname which was teachers previously.. which is dropdown list.